Display multiple images while keeping their original aspect ratio
I am trying to display multiple images (using  of Nextjs) inside a container while keep its aspect ratio.
Here is my implementation so far:
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            {s3Url.map((url, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="relative">
                    {loadingStates[i] && (
                        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-200 z-10">
                            <Loader2 className="animate-spin text-muted-foreground" />
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <Image
                        src={url}
                        layout="responsive"
                        objectFit="contain"
                        width={100}
                        height={100}
                        alt="uploaded image"
                        onLoadingComplete={() => handleImageLoad(i)}
                        onClick={() => handleOnClick(url)}
                        className="cursor-pointer"
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>

But there are gaps between them because the image is contained inside the div with className='relative'. See the image below:
(https://i.sstatic.net/ecK7XivI.png)
How can I remove the gap?

try this, change first line to <div className="columns-2 gap-4"> . to get more advance options you can search for react masonry

@NullEe thank you, setting <div className="columns-2 gap-4"> does work. Also react masonry does look neat, I'll look more into it.
